# Передать в php данные из localstorage

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

Есть две php страницы, на первой странице есть ссылка при клике на которую происходит переход на вторую страницу и на ней выводится информация из MYSQL таблицы.
При клике на ссылку в localstorage записывается название таблицы и при переходе на другую страницу на нее должна выводится информация из той таблицы которая записалась в localstorage.
В localstorage все записывается отлично а вот как передать теперь название таблицы в php что бы выводить информацию на страницу именно из той таблицы название которой лежит в localstorage???

Comment: Передавайте get параметром в ссылке - самое простое.

Comment: А пробовал аяксом передать, не получилось.
Как передать в ссылке?

Comment: `domain.info/?table=mytable`(где mytable - это название вашей таблицы) обычная ссылка с get параметрами. Вам надо запомнить, что php отрабатывает на сервере и возвращает готовый html документ. Если работать с аяксом, то формирование данных на клиенте надо делать силами javascript. И для этого должен быть отдельный php файл, который возвращает только полезные данные, а не весь html документ.

Comment: А как потом использовать этот get параметр?
Как в php его получить?

Comment: [reserved.variables.get](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.get.php)

Comment: Большое спасибо!